# Can someone explain to me the meaning of field SELECTABILITY in relation to Cardinality?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-indexes

read this http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/cardinality-versus-selectivity/

but still doesnt really sink in.

so let's say, we have 993 records, and a cardinality of 13, that means there are 13 unique/ possible values out of 993 records. Its selectability is 0.0130 or 1.3% right?

Now, what does 1.3% mean? All I know that lower the worse, and the higher selectability is better meaning more unique values and the sql engine optimizer is happy. BUT, how can i explain 1.3% ?

1.3% of???
when i select a row, variability is only 1.3% of the 13 possible records?

Sorry, it has been like 20+ years since i had my stat classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.3% is of all the rows in the table, but you are confusing yourself by treating it as a percentage.

When you query a table, you want to get to the relevant rows as quickly as possible. The database has to choose which index to search first, and you want this index to return as small a set of rows as possible, with the relevant rows inside.

Imagine that you are looking for John Smith the guitar repairer in the Yellow Pages. There are 10,000 names and you have 2 choices:

- Browse through the Last Name index, where all last names are grouped by their first character. This gives you a cardinality of 26, selectivity = 0.26%.
- Browse through the Guitar Repair category. There are 500 business categories in your city so cardinality = 500, selectivity = 5%.

If you choose the first index, you then have to search through S-group, which contains on average 10,000 / 26 = 384.6 names.

If you choose the second index, you will have to search through the Guitar Repairers, which contains on average 10,000 / 500 = 20 names.

Clearly, the Business Category is a better index than the Last Name because you can narrow down your search range a lot faster. That's all it means by selectivity: you can get to the rows you want as quickly as possible.

Comment: I see, I get it now. Thank you Zoff